# open a file when user click on a link

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement to open a PPT when a user clicks on the image.
I tried by using the below code, but was not able to open the PPT when i clicked on the image or the button but its downloading the PPT file whenever i click on the image or the button. Please suggest what changes need to be done in order to open a PPT file on user click.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Click to open Report: 
    <a href="" onclick="window.open('myFOlder/report.pptx')">
       <img border="0" src="images/myPowerpoint.jpg" width="100" height="100">
    </a>
</p>
<input type="button" value="Open Report" onClick="window.open('myFOlder/report.pptx');">
</body>
</html>
```

PS: No external libraries should be used as our project doesn't support any external libraries.

Comment: You can't execute functions like this from a Web Browser.

Comment: you can for downloading the file by add `download` attribute to `a` tag like this: `Click to open Report: <a href="myFOlder/report.pptx" download>`

Comment: just FYI `onclick` is not always equal to `onClick` and you should always use `onclick`

Comment: Can any browser open a PPT file (without addons etc)? OF course it has to download the file

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is impossible.  Since most Web browsers don't support PowerPoint documents without extensions, they will automatically download them.  You could, however, upload the presentation to a website that could display PowerPoint documents (e.g. Google Drive), and include a link to the uploaded file.